# Java classes in different files compile

Tags: java, design-patterns, compilation

I have been reading a design patterns book and it is full of java. I just have some basic understanding of java. I am now trying to implement some of the codes, but I am facing some difficulties. 
For example, there are different classes written in different files. All of these classes have been made into a package. Now, when I try to javac the java file where the main is, it complains that it cannot find the other classes (in this case, WeatherData and CurrentConditionsDisplay).

Here is the main file:

```
package headfirst.src.observer.weatherobservable;

public class WeatherStation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WeatherData weatherData = new WeatherData();
        CurrentConditionsDisplay currentConditions = new CurrentConditionsDisplay(weatherData);`
        //StatisticsDisplay statisticsDisplay = new StatisticsDisplay(weatherData);
        //ForecastDisplay forecastDisplay = new ForecastDisplay(weatherData);

        weatherData.setMeasurements(80, 65, 30.4f);
        weatherData.setMeasurements(82, 70, 29.2f);
        weatherData.setMeasurements(78, 90, 29.2f);
    }
}
```

I just need to know how to compile the files properly. The java code in the book is pretty basic, and I can understand it. But I just cannot get the files to compile!!!

Comment: What command are you using to compile the class? Do each of the classes have identical package declarations at the top? Are each of the classes in the same directory?

Comment: Now everything is working fine. Thanks for the help~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to compile the files via command-line. As I see you have packages, please first try this in an IDE like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to get hands on "how to run the programs?"

Via command-line you need to pass the approriate classpath, which you can learn at a later stage.

Comment: yes, i have been trying using command-line. I will try with Eclipse.

Comment: Hi, you were right. I was not using the appropriate classpath. I got my hands on Head First Java. There is one chapter about packages and it gave me a good explanation about packages. Now everything is compiling well. Btw, I don't know how to close this post?

Comment: Great !. Nothing else needs to be done in respect of this post. Accepting an answer is the action you can to do from your side, and assigning a bounty if you don't get the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely required to compile all the files together. e.g.

```
$ javac *.java
```

Alternatively you can build the others into a .jar file and reference that on the command line e.g.

```
$ javac -cp my.jar File.java
```

etc.